# MalformedCookieException: Invalid 'expires' attribute

Tags: cookies, jmeter

We are using header manager in our JMeter script and getting the following exception in one of the request responses. I tried with all the available options in the header manager but no luck.

Response from Server where it threw exception was- Set-Cookie: X-Region=B; expires=1581079580; path=/

I looked on multiple sites but no resolution. Could you please suggest a resolution for this exception-

*org.apache.http.cookie.MalformedCookieException: Invalid 'expires' attribute: 1581079580
    at org.apache.http.impl.cookie.LaxExpiresHandler.parse(LaxExpiresHandler.java:161) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.http.impl.cookie.RFC6265CookieSpec.parse(RFC6265CookieSpec.java:181) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC4CookieHandler.addCookieFromHeader(HC4CookieHandler.java:125) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.0 r1840934]*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want to fix from JMeter side?

As per RFC 6265 the [format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.1.1) of the [`Expires` attribute](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.1) is following:

```
cookie-date     = *delimiter date-token-list *delimiter
   date-token-list = date-token *( 1*delimiter date-token )
   date-token      = 1*non-delimiter

   delimiter       = %x09 / %x20-2F / %x3B-40 / %x5B-60 / %x7B-7E
   non-delimiter   = %x00-08 / %x0A-1F / DIGIT / ":" / ALPHA / %x7F-FF
   non-digit       = %x00-2F / %x3A-FF

   day-of-month    = 1*2DIGIT ( non-digit *OCTET )
   month           = ( "jan" / "feb" / "mar" / "apr" /
                       "may" / "jun" / "jul" / "aug" /
                       "sep" / "oct" / "nov" / "dec" ) *OCTET
   year            = 2*4DIGIT ( non-digit *OCTET )
   time            = hms-time ( non-digit *OCTET )
   hms-time        = time-field ":" time-field ":" time-field
   time-field      = 1*2DIGIT
```

My expectation is that the server should return something like:

```
Expires=Fri, 07 Feb 2020 12:46:00 GMT
```

So you need to raise a bug against your application instead of looking for the workaround.

If you're absolutely sure that your application works as expected (which is not the case in my opinion) you won't be able to automatically handle the cookies using HTTP Cookie Manager, you will have to extract them from previous response [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header using i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and add [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header with the extracted values using [HTTP Header Manager](https://guides.blazemeter.com/g/the-jmeter-pros-load-testing-checklist/23672)

Comment: This application is getting the cookie information from AWS so the development team cannot change that considering LoadRunner or Fiddler were easily handling the same cookie without any exception. Is there a way to write custom cookie manager like we can write custom samplers? If not, I would consider your earlier reply as Answer.

Comment: It's possible to write custom "anything", in your case you can amend [this line](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2.1/src/protocol/http/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/control/HC4CookieHandler.java#L124) to manually add cookies and not rely on whatever cookie handler. But I repeat, the cookie "expires" attribute doesn't conform to the standard so it's a workaround, not the solution. Just in case check out [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide/) article for more information

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your 'expires' attribute is not compliant with https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265 There is epoch time `1581079580` But there should be time in format specified by https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.3.1 E.g.: `Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT` Do you have a cookie policy set to `standard` or `standard-strict` (RFC6265)?

Comment: The exception, I pasted was when I had Standard in my cookie manager .. though when I change it to other methods the stack trace changes accordinly like Netscape option will have netscapeparser exception in logs. Tried with standard-strict too.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the HTTP Authorization Manager does this error occures. If you have, try with toggled off this.